# Select Duplicated Rows with only one different Column And Group it

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

```
SELECT
    a.FirstName,
    a.LastName,
    c.Country,
    SUM(b.Scores) AS Score
FROM names a
INNER JOIN countries c
    ON a.id = c.cid
INNER JOIN scores b
    ON a.id = b.sid
WHERE a.id = :id
GROUP BY c.Country
ORDER BY Score ASC
```

I'm trying to use this query to `select` rows with `duplicated` but with different `countries` So from these tables

```
           names                           countries                       scores
[id  --  FirstName  -- LastName]    [id --  cid  --  Country]      [id   --  sid  --  Score]
[1   --   FName1    --  LName1 ]    [1  --   1   --  USA    ]      [1    --   1   --      5] 
[2   --   FName2    --  LName2 ]    [2  --   1   --  France ]      [2    --   1   --      6]
[3   --   FName3    --  LName3 ]    [3  --   1   --  Germany]      [3    --   2   --      7]
[4   --   FName4    --  LName4 ]    [4  --   2   --  Germany]      [4    --   2   --      8] 
                                    [5  --   2   --  Czech  ]      [5    --   2   --      2]
                                    [6  --   3   --  Germany]      [6    --   4   --     10]
                                    [7  --   4   --  France ]      [7    --   3   --     15]
```

The statics supposed to be

```
{id[1] -> FName1 -> LName1}--{cid[1] -> USA, France, Germany}--{sid[1] -> 11}
{id[2] -> FName2 -> LName2}--{cid[2] -> Czech    ,   Germany}--{sid[2] -> 17}
{id[3] -> FName3 -> LName3}--{cid[3] ->        Germany      }--{sid[3] -> 10}
{id[4] -> FName4 -> LName4}--{cid[4] ->        France       }--{sid[4] -> 15}
```

I want to get these data like the following HTML structure

```css
.Container div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 10px;
}
.Container div div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="Master German">German</div>
    <div id="German">
        <div class="Container">
           <div id='FName2 German'>
                <div>FName2</div>
                <div>LName2</div>
            </div>
            <div id='FName1 German'>
                <div>FName1</div>
                <div>LName1</div>
            </div>
            <div id='FName3 German'>
                <div>FName3</div>
                <div>LName3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Master France">France</div>
    <div id="France">
        <div class="Container">
           <div id='FName4 France'>
                <div>FName4</div>
                <div>LName4</div>
            </div>
            <div id='FName1 France'>
                <div>FName1</div>
                <div>LName1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div id="Master Czech">Czech</div>
    <div id="Czech">
        <div class="Container">
            <div id='FName2 Czech'>
                <div>FName2</div>
                <div>LName2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="Master USA">USA</div>
    <div id="USA">
        <div class="Container">
            <div id='FName1 USA'>
                <div>FName1</div>
                <div>LName1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i'm tried to use on my query was the following `PHP` code

```
$pre = null;
echo "<div>";
$end = "";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $FName = $row['FirstName'];
    $LName = $row['LastName'];
    $Country = $row['Country'];

    if ($Country != $pre) {
        echo $end;
        echo "<div id='Master $Country'>$Country</div>";
        echo "<div id='$Country'>";
    }
    $end = "</div>
</div>";
    $pre = $Country;

    echo "
<div id='$FName USA'>
    <div>$FName</div>
    <div>$LName</div>
</div>";
}
echo $end;
echo "</div>";
```

But doesn't work as intended at all and gives me a headache trying to fix it, But with no hope.

Is there a better way to handle this? from SQL side or PHP side or mixed if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "rows", I interpret your question as `names` with multiple counries.  If so:

```
SELECT n.FirstName, n.LastName,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.Country) as countries, SUM(s.Scores) AS Score
FROM names n INNER JOIN
     countries c
     ON n.id = c.cid INNER JOIN
     scores s
     ON n.id = s.sid
WHERE n.id = :id
GROUP BY n.id, n.FirstName, n.LastName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.country) > 1
ORDER BY Score ASC;
```

Comment: Does this solution requires some changes in the PHP code to use `foreach($countries as $country)`? Since i get only one HTML `div` with id `French, German` if i just defined `countries` as a variable.

Comment: Also, I don't get any values at all, Unless the duplication exists. So i changed the `HAVING` to `> 0` and returned to the previous problem.